# How to extract sms.db from non-jailbroken iphone on linux

Tags: iphone, sqlite, sms, fuse

Objective: Extract the sms.db sms text message database from an Iphone 4S.

I have installed ifuse on ubuntu 12.04 and am able to browse certain folders.  None seem to contain the 'sms.db' file.

It is possible to extract the sms.db using freely available tools on linux?

Comment: It's in `/var/mobile/Library/SMS/sms.db`.

Comment: It don't have the `/var` file system available:  `$ sudo ifuse /media/iPhone; $ sudo ls -1 /media/iPhone 
Books
com.apple.itdbprep.postprocess.lock
DCIM
Downloads
HighlandPark
iTunes_Control
PhotoData
Photos
PhotoStreamsData
Podcasts
PublicStaging
Purchases
Recordings
$`

Comment: `sudo ifuse --root /media/iPhone`

Comment: As stated in the subject line, my Iphone is not jailbroken: `$ sudo ifuse --root /media/iPhone 
Failed to start AFC service 'com.apple.afc2' on the device.
This service enables access to the root filesystem of your device.
Your device needs to be jailbroken and have the AFC2 service installed.`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know yet how to access the SMS.DB file directly from the phone. But if you backup an iPhone using for example iTunes, you can then read the SMS.DB file from within the backup. It will be SHA-1 hashed (the file name will be gibberish), but it should still be a .DB file. You'll need iPhone Analyzer to unhash the file names, or something similar. Then you can load it into SQLite.
Please post here if you find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out a way on how to access it with Jailbroken devices... It miiiiiight be the same if you aren't jailbroken based on what the Github says (https://github.com/libimobiledevice/ifuse)

Anyways, open a terminal

```
Sudo su
```

now make a folder in your home and direct ifuse to that folder

```
ifuse --root /home/<INSERT NAME>/<INSERT NAME OF FOLDER>
```

Now you gotta open that folder as root

```
nautilus
```

Browse through your /home/ and find the folder.

It should be in

```
/var/mobile/Library/SMS/sms.db
```

Then you just copy it to your desktop and your good to go!